# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in on line 285

Tags: xampp

```
$get_list_pro = "select * from products where product_list='$list_id'";
$run_list_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_list_pro);
$count_lists = mysqli_num_rows($run_list_pro);*
```

Comment: Some one can help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when your **select** query is wrong. The item that you are selecting using `select * from products where product_list='$list_id`. Does not exists in **table produc**t.